# Character array address and integer array address

Tags: c++

I'm curious with this problem

```
int p[] = {1,2,3};
cout << p;
```

it will output address of the first element(1)
but.....

```
char p[] = {'a','b'};
cout << p;
```

it will not output the address of the first element but it will output the entire array "ab".
why does it happened ?

Comment: Likely because of how `std::cout` is overloaded for each. For the former, it's likely a general overload for arrays, that just outputs the address of the array. For the second, it's likely specialized since it's a string-like data type.

Comment: The second example is undefined behavior because `<<` is expecting a null-terminated C-style string and your array is not null-terminated.

Answer (score 2):

The first will use `std::basic_ostream<>::operator <<(const void *)` which will just output the address. The second uses `std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<> &, const char  *)` which will output the character array just as if it were a string literal.